# R shiny 2nd UI action button cannot work

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating a Shiny app with a login form. After logging in it switches to the 2nd form.

The submit button on the 2nd form does not work. I tried changing submit button to action button, but it didn't help.

My app code as below:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
uiOutput("ui")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
USER <- reactiveValues(Logged = FALSE)
observe({
if (USER$Logged == FALSE) {
  output$ui <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      h2("Hello", align = "center"),
      div(
        id = "login",
        wellPanel(
          textInput("userName", "Username"),
          passwordInput("passwd", "Password"),
          br(), actionButton("Login", "Log in")
        )
      )
    )
  })
} else if (USER$Logged == TRUE) {
  output$ui <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      tabPanel(""),
      pageWithSidebar(
        headerPanel(
          ""
        ),
        sidebarPanel(
          actionButton("logout", "Logout"),
          sliderInput("range", 
                      label = "Range of interest:",
                      min = 0, max = 100, value = c(0, 100)),
          submitButton("submit")
        ),
        mainPanel(tableOutput("aaa"),textOutput("min_max"))
      )
    )
  })

  output$min_max <- renderText({ 
    paste("You have chosen a range that goes from",
          input$range[1], "to", input$range[2])
  })
}
})

observeEvent(input$Login, {
USER$Logged <- TRUE
})

observeEvent(input$logout, {
USER$Logged <- FALSE
})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting the shiny documentation:

"Submit buttons are unusual Shiny inputs, and we recommend using actionButton instead of submitButton when you want to delay a reaction. See this article (http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/action-buttons.html) for more information (including a demo of how to "translate" code using a submitButton to code using an actionButton)."

In your code, you'll need another instance of
observeEvent, i.e. observeEvent(input$submit) to capture the occurrence of the button push.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you so much! after read the article you share, I try to add another group reactiveValues and observeEvent to response button, now it works well.

Comment: Great! I'm glad it was helpful. Thanks for accepting the answer.